# PHP count object property occurrences

Tags: php, arrays, object, count

I have a PHP object like below and all I want to know whats the the easiest way to get a count of objects where the property 'typeId' = 3

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC Object
        (
            [id] => 13
            [typeId] => 3
            [sortOrder] => 0
        )
    [1] => ABC Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [typeId] => 2
            [sortOrder] => 0
        )
    [2] => ABC Object
        (
            [id] => 14
            [typeId] => 4
            [sortOrder] => 0
        )
    [3] => ABC Object
        (
            [id] => 15
            [typeId] => 3
            [sortOrder] => 0
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `foreach` counter should do:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $object) {
    if ($object->typeId == 3) $count++;
}
```

No need to over complicate things

Comment: straight forward, I guess I should of spent a bit more time trying to solve it myself.   So simple when you know how. thanks  =)

Comment: blimey im looking at this old question of mine now wondering how on earth I didnt know how to do this.  I guess in the last 1.5 years Ive learnt alot and cant imagine me asking something so simple anymore hehe

Comment: @SubstanceD we all have those moments

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, a much nicer solution is to use the `array_filter` function:

```
$newarray = array_filter( $old_array, function($object) { return $object->typeId == 3; } );
```

(note: inline functions only work since PHP 5.3)

Comment: This is _a lot slower_ than using a simple `foreach` loop though

Comment: How can it be slower? Have you do measurements?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did go with the foreach loop from Petah above but I didnt know about inline functions  so I've learnt something else too.  nice one =)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a temporary variable called `objectCount` or something similar, loop through your array and when you find an object where the typeId equals 3 add 1 to `objectCount`.