# Count objects in an array (php)

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a complete newbie at php, but anyway, here it goes:

I want to count the amount of `["completed"]=> bool(true)` in the array below.

I was able to count the total by doing this: `$totalCount = count($object->data);`. Do I need to do a `foreach()` in order to get the amount of `completed` ones or can I get around it by just doing some kind of `count()`?

Thanks!

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(232) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(13081073106396)
      ["completed"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(13160080793822)
      ["completed"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
```

Comment: Looks like this has already been answered:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291027/php-count-object-property-occurrences][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291027/php-count-object-property-occurrences

Comment: You can use the answer that @gratz is referring to, just remember to reference object properties with the `->` operator, so it is `$obj->data` and not `$obj['data']` because you are dealing with objects and not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that might work:

```
var $count = 0;
foreach($stdClass->data as $obj)
    if($obj->completed)
        $count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider $oObject is your object

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($oObject),true);
```

then apply simple array count like

```
echo count($array);
```

It will return total count of data. Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback to count:

```
$countCompleted = 0;

array_map(function ($n) use $countCompleted {
    if ( $n->completed === true )
         $countCompleted ++;
}, $objectMap->data );
```